# Ubuntu seem to stopped tracking filesystem changes

Tags: nautilus, files, filesystem

I'm using Ubuntu 20.10 and recently have the problem that applications don't seem to track file changes anymore. For example when I download a file it's not shown inside my download directory until I refresh nautilus with F5. My Nextcloud Client is showing me a message that it can't track file changes instantly anymore and hugo is also not longer tracking file changes automatically.

I had the same behavior under Ubuntu 20.04 a few month ago, but after a fresh install of my current 20.10 system things where working fine again until now.

I found a temporary solution for this with increasing the max_user_watches value (default value in file is 65536):

```
echo 1000000 | sudo tee /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches
```

But it's gone after every restart.

I can't figure out why this behaviour is happening. I wasn't making any system changes recently. Does anyone have an explanation or solution for it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To set `max_user_watches` and keep the value across reboots, do this:

```
echo "fs.inotify.max_user_watches=1000000" | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf
sudo sysctl -p
```

If you are running daemons that watch the file system closely, such as backup jobs, NextCloud sync, DropBox sync, and OneDrive sync, you will run out of watchers. Increasing the value is fine, though it does come at a cost in terms of memory consumption. Try not to go overboard